# Prove that $n$ hypersurfaces with cyclic permutations of the last $n-1$ variables only intersect if all the variables have the same value.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, symmetric-functions

Suppose that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I have an equation $F(x,y,z,\dots,n)=0$ with the property that it is symmetric in the last $(n-1)$ variables $\{y,z,\dots,n\}$, but *not* in the first variable $x$. For example, if $(1,2,3,\dots,n)$ is a solution, then $(1,3,2,\dots,n)$ is also a solution (found by permuting the second and third numbers), but $(2,1,3,\dots,n)$ might not be.

I now want to solve the following cyclic system of equations:

$$F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=0$$ $$F(x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n,x_1)=0$$ $$...$$ $$F(x_n,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})=0$$

Is it true that the solution must satisfy the property that $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n$?

EDIT: I also want to ensure that all $x_i>0$.

Comment: $a+bc = b+ca = c+ab = 0 $ has $ (-1, 1, 1)$ as a solution, so no / not necessarily so.

Comment: @CalvinLin- Thank you, I will accept that as an answer if you'd like

Comment: @CalvinLin- Sorry I have the additional condition that all $x_i>0$. Is there still a counter-example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(a-4) + (b-4)(c-4) = 0\\
(b-4) + (c-4)(a-4) = 0\\
(c-4) + (a-4)(b-4) = 0 $$

has $ (3, 5, 5)$ as a solution, so no / not necessarily so.

Comment: Sorry should have thought of this myself. By just shifting the origin, you were able to get a positive solution.